# Remove everything before first # in mysql field

Tags: regex, mysql

Excuse my ignorance.

I need to replace all data in a mysql field before and including the first # .

example     field = golfers

data         at the first hole the golfer missed a 9 inch putt and said "#hit it bad

new data     hit it bad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
update table set new_column_name = substring(column_name, instr(column_name, '#') + 1);
```

Comment: Gave me eveything but the # both before and after.
----------------------------------------
update content set metakey = substring(alias, instr(alias, '#') + 1)
----------------------------------
table = content , metakey is new field, alias is old field

Comment: yep that should work fine. can you give me an example of what you got instead?

Comment: at the first hole the golfer missed a 9 inch putt and said "hit it bad

Comment: and what do you get from `select substring('test#hello', instr('test#hello', '#') + 1);` - it should just return hello

Comment: My fault I used wrong colum with the # in it - worked perfectly